# elastic beanstalk customize the build process

Tags: vue.js, command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, vue-cli

I am aiming to add in an elastic-beanstalk build step for my express/vue app built using the vue cli. I've done so before in heroku doing the following:

1. Push to Heroku
2. Heroku installs server dependencies
3. Heroku runs 'heroku-postbuild'
4. We tell Heroku to install client dependencies
5. We tell Heroku to run 'npm run build'

I've tried googling for many days on adding a aws-postbuild config in my package.json file like I did previously for heroku.

in my package.json file i've done this for heroku and it has worked previously
`"heroku-postbuild" : "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"`

I can't figure out how to configure for elastic beanstalk cli. Any help is greatly appreciated.